# Having same sub-sub domain name in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, subdomain

We like to add additional domain to our existing forest so it will be like this:

usm.local 
-> asset.usm.local
-> kk.usm.local -> asset.kk.usm.local
-> ee.usm.local  -> asset.ee.usm.local

Is it possible to have same sub/sub-sub domain name - asset.*? What's the catch?

Comment: ASSET domain will be use for pc join.

Comment: BTW the name is fictional.